# Getting values from Typescript enum with strings

Tags: typescript

I am trying to get the values out of this enum:

```
enum Sizes {
  Tiny = "Tiny",
  VerySmall = "Very Small",
  Small = "Small",
  Medium = "Medium",
  Large = "Large",
  VeryLarge = "Very Large"
}
```

With the following code as suggested in other StackOverflows, I get the following output:

```
var text=""
for (var size in Sizes) {
    text = text + "\n" + size;
}

console.log(text);
```

---

```
Tiny
VerySmall
Very Small
Small
Medium
Large
VeryLarge
Very Large
```

I do not want the entries VerySmall and VeryLarge, why are these appearing and how can I get my desired results?

Thanks!

Comment: Your for loop will print only keys, to get values, use Sizes[size].

Comment: Also the output you posted is not correct, it can't print both key and value at the same time with your logic.

Comment: @Deshak9 Here's the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/98o7cysv/

Comment: It actually seems to be a TypeScript-Bug. Even the recommended way in the Microsoft docs leads to the same result.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the typescript compiler being used is pre-2.4 where they added string value support in enums. Usually there's a reverse mapping from values to enums and values are generally numbers. But if you attempt to use strings prior to 2.4, the compiler wouldn't know what to do about it (and would actually produce errors) but will still generate the source.

Compare 2.4:

```
var Sizes;
(function (Sizes) {
    Sizes["Tiny"] = "Tiny";
    Sizes["VerySmall"] = "Very Small";
    Sizes["Small"] = "Small";
    Sizes["Medium"] = "Medium";
    Sizes["Large"] = "Large";
    Sizes["VeryLarge"] = "Very Large";
})(Sizes || (Sizes = {}));
```

To 2.3:

```
var Sizes;
(function (Sizes) {
    Sizes[Sizes["Tiny"] = "Tiny"] = "Tiny";
    Sizes[Sizes["VerySmall"] = "Very Small"] = "VerySmall";
    Sizes[Sizes["Small"] = "Small"] = "Small";
    Sizes[Sizes["Medium"] = "Medium"] = "Medium";
    Sizes[Sizes["Large"] = "Large"] = "Large";
    Sizes[Sizes["VeryLarge"] = "Very Large"] = "VeryLarge";
})(Sizes || (Sizes = {}));
```

And 2.3 without string values:

```
var Sizes;
(function (Sizes) {
    Sizes[Sizes["Tiny"] = 0] = "Tiny";
    Sizes[Sizes["VerySmall"] = 1] = "VerySmall";
    Sizes[Sizes["Small"] = 2] = "Small";
    Sizes[Sizes["Medium"] = 3] = "Medium";
    Sizes[Sizes["Large"] = 4] = "Large";
    Sizes[Sizes["VeryLarge"] = 5] = "VeryLarge";
})(Sizes || (Sizes = {}));
```

If you wanted to force that reverse mapping in 2.4 and up, you could assert the values to `any`.

```
enum Sizes {
  Tiny = <any>"Tiny",
  VerySmall = <any>"Very Small",
  Small = <any>"Small",
  Medium = <any>"Medium",
  Large = <any>"Large",
  VeryLarge = <any>"Very Large"
}
```

Just call it a feature.

Comment: You can check out the source too to see how it emits enums. [2.3](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.3.4/src/compiler/transformers/ts.ts#L2496) vs [2.4](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.4.2/src/compiler/transformers/ts.ts#L2565)

Comment: This doesn't work as expected in the following example: https://jsfiddle.net/7jk6z3n2/

Comment: No, forcing them to be `any` will cause this to happen in current versions. To fix your fiddle, you need to force a specific version of typescript to be used (which doesn't seem to be possible).

Comment: jsfiddle uses version typescript version 1.7.3, which _does not_ support string values for enums. [See for yourself](http://fiddle.jshell.net/js/typescript/typescript.js), look for the `ts.version`.

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScrit

```
enum Sizes {
  Tiny = "Tiny",
  VerySmall = "Very Small",
  Small = "Small",
  Medium = "Medium",
  Large = "Large",
  VeryLarge = "Very Large"
}
class Test {
  constructor() {
    let text = '';

    for (const key in Sizes) {
      if (Sizes.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        text += Sizes[key] + '<br/>';
      }
    }
    console.log(text);

    text = '';
    Object.keys(Sizes).map(key => text += Sizes[key] + '<br/>');
    console.log(text);
  }
}
let t = new Test();
```

Remember that a for-In should have a if-Statement!

Both `console.log(text)`, should output the same string.

```
Tiny<br/>Very Small<br/>Small<br/>Medium<br/>Large<br/>Very Large<br/>
```

If you log `Sizes[size]` to console after the for-In you will imagine [what](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) happens and [why](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) you get the values.

Comment: Try out here  [TypeScriptPlayground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html)
I test it and it works, but remove the 'export' before 'class'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys` to get the enum keys and log the values, like this:

```
enum Sizes {
  Tiny = "Tiny",
  VerySmall = "Very Small",
  Small = "Small",
  Medium = "Medium",
  Large = "Large",
  VeryLarge = "Very Large"
}

for (const size of Object.keys(Sizes)) {
    console.log(Sizes[size]);
}
```

Output:

```
Tiny
Very Small
Small
Medium
Large
Very Large
```

Transpiled example:

```js
var Sizes;
(function (Sizes) {
    Sizes["Tiny"] = "Tiny";
    Sizes["VerySmall"] = "Very Small";
    Sizes["Small"] = "Small";
    Sizes["Medium"] = "Medium";
    Sizes["Large"] = "Large";
    Sizes["VeryLarge"] = "Very Large";
})(Sizes || (Sizes = {}));
for (var _i = 0, _a = Object.keys(Sizes); _i < _a.length; _i++) {
    var size = _a[_i];
    console.log(Sizes[size]);
}
```